# How to set a workflow to not fire on a certain day?

Tags: trigger, time-dependent-workflow

I have a WF designed to detect cases that weren't handled in the past 24 hours and notify TL. I want this WF to fire everyday, apart from Saturday.

Status = New and Case.CreateDate is not a Saturday.

Can someone please help me with the formula?

Thanks so much in advance
Rachel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write formula to know created date is Saturday. Use following formula.

```
If(MOD( DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1985,6,24),7) = 5,"Saturday", "Some other Day")
```

Update :

```
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status ,'New'), IF(MOD( DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1985,6,24),7) = 5, False, True)), True, False)
```

Comment: Thank you Prabhat. I tried to combine this with the Status = New condition, like so: I changed the rule to "formula evaluates to True" and then -    IF(
AND(ISPICKVAL( Status ,'New'), 
(IF(MOD( DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1985,6,24),7) = 5, False, True)), True, False)
) but I get a syntax error, saying that the IF expects 3 parameters and received only 1. I tried adding another ')' to close the AND, but I get another error. please advise.

Comment: Use updated code in the answer and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, it seems ok now. I didn't understand your second comment - where is this checkbox? I'm returning Boolean since the rule criteria is "formula evaluates to True".

Comment: @RachelS. - If you go this route it will not notify for any case created on Saturday even if they were not handled by Monday. What you are doing here is excluding ALL cases created on Saturday from notification regardless of if the meet the criteria of not being handled in the next 24 hours. What if a case is created on Saturday and no-one handles it on sunday, would you not want the WF to send an alert then?

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks! It's ok, since somebody will always handle them on Sunday. Saturday is our problematic day.